# How to send extra parameters to the serializer, not included in the model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to send parameters to the serializer that do not exist in the model, so the serializer delete this data

I also have a nested serializer with a custom `.create()` function

This is the request data sended by the frontend ajax.

```
 request data = {'data': [{'usuario': 269, 'coworkers': [328, 209], 'inicio': '2019-01-24T23:30:43.926Z', 'estado': 'progress', 'operacion': {'orden': 24068, 'proceso': 'ALEZADO FINAL-TORNO CNC T7 1'}}, {'usuario': 269, 'coworkers': [208, 212], 'inicio': '2019-01-24T23:30:43.926Z', 'estado': 'progress', 'operacion': {'orden': 24067, 'proceso': 'ALEZADO FINAL-TORNO CNC T7 1'}}]}
```

**Model:**

```
class TiempoOperacion(models.Model):
    inicio = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    fin = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    operacion = models.ForeignKey(Operacion, related_name='tiempos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    motivo_pausa = models.CharField(max_length=140, default=None, null=True)
    estado = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=TASKS_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=UNACTION,
    )
```

**Viewset:**

```
class TiempoOperacionViewSet(CustomViewSet):

    model_class = TiempoOperacion
    serializer_class = TiempoOperacionSerializer
    pagination_class = SmallResultsSetPagination
    order_by = '-inicio'

    def create(self, request):
        datos = request.data.get('listorders') if 'listorders' in request.data  else request.data

        tiemposerializer = self.serializer_class(data=datos, many=True, fields=('coworkers', 'operacion'))

        if tiemposerializer.is_valid():
            tiemposerializer.save()
            return Response(tiemposerializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(tiemposerializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class TiempoOperacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    operacion = OperacionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TiempoOperacion
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validate_data):
        operacion_data = validate_data.pop('operacion')
        print (f"\n\n validate_data : {validate_data} \n\n")

        if not operacion_data:
            raise ValidationError({
                'operacion': 'This field object is required.'
            })

        coworkers = validate_data.get('coworkers')

        query_operaciones = Operacion.objects.filter(**operacion_data)[:1]
        if query_operaciones.count() > 0:
            operacion = query_operaciones[0]
        else:
            operacion = Operacion.objects.create(**operacion_data)
        tiempo_obj = validate_data
        tiempo = TiempoOperacion.objects.create(operacion=operacion, **tiempo_obj)
        if coworkers:
            tiempos_list = []

            for coworker in coworkers:
                tiempo_obj.update({'usuario': coworker})
                tiempos_list.append(TiempoOperacion(operacion=operacion, **tiempo_obj))

            tiempos = TiempoOperacion.objects.bulk_create(tiempos_list)

        return tiempo
```

I hope to get `coworkers` in `create` serialize function

But I only have:

```
validate_data : {'inicio': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 24, 18, 12, 25, 251000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Bogota' -05-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>), 'usuario': '269', 'estado': 'progress'}
```

Comment: Please, add the whole declarations of the viewset and the serializer, not juts the `create()` methods

Comment: I solve with this code inside my serializer class:

`def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data`

Like a [Custom fields DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) documentation

Comment: You should answer your own question with the final code, in case somebody has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write the to_internal_value function

```
class TiempoOperacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    operacion = OperacionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TiempoOperacion
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validate_data):
        operacion_data = validate_data.pop('operacion')

        if not operacion_data:
            raise ValidationError({
                'operacion': 'This field object is required.'
            })

        coworkers = validate_data.pop('coworkers')

        query_operaciones = Operacion.objects.filter(**operacion_data)[:1]
        if query_operaciones.count() > 0:
            operacion = query_operaciones[0]
        else:
            operacion = Operacion.objects.create(**operacion_data)
        tiempo_obj = validate_data
        tiempo = TiempoOperacion.objects.create(operacion=operacion, **tiempo_obj)
        if coworkers:
            tiempos_list = []

            for coworker in coworkers:
                tiempo_obj.update({'usuario': coworker})
                tiempos_list.append(TiempoOperacion(operacion=operacion, **tiempo_obj))

            tiempos = TiempoOperacion.objects.bulk_create(tiempos_list)

        return tiempo

    #This function rewrite the value validated_data mentioned in above function
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if not "coworkers" in data:
            data['coworkers'] = []
        return data
```